# unity C# bool and to set false by time....?

Tags: c#, boolean, unity-game-engine

this is My Code:

```
if ( run && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.K)) {
    anim.SetInteger ("State", 4);
    slide = true;
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.K)) {
    slide = false;
    anim.SetInteger ("State", 0);
}
```

My problem: if I hold the (`KeyCode.K`) than `slide` is still `true` which I don´t want.

I need set `slide` to `true` just once, or to `false` after 2 seconds only.

I hope you all understand what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making `slide` a property which will set your integer :

```
public bool Slide
{
    get { return slide; }
    set
    {
        if ( value == slide ) return;

        slide = value;

        if( slide ) anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
        else anim.SetInteger("State", 0);
    }
}
```

One of the many possible options would be to create a `Coroutine` that just resets the flag back to `false` :

```
IEnumerator StartSlide()
{
    const float MAX_TIME = 2.0f; // time to wait before resetting the flag
    Slide = true;
    float timeNow = 0.0f;
    while ( timeNow < MAX_TIME && Slide )
    {
       timeNow += Time.deltaTime;
       yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
    Slide = false;
}
```

And to use this you can call :

```
if ( run && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K) && !Slide )
{
     StartCoroutine(StartSlide());
}
```

You can also use this with `GetKeyUp` method :

```
if ( Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.K) && Slide )
{
    Slide = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, for suggest me to using "Coroutine".

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update{

    if ( key_K && run && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.K)) {
            key_K = false;

            StartCoroutine ("coRoutine_keyK");

        }

}


IEnumerator coRoutine_keyK(){
        slide = true;
        anim.SetInteger ("State", 4);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);

        slide = false;
        anim.SetInteger ("State", 0);

        key_K = true;
    }
```